# Place a marker in each country with mapbox

Tags: mapbox, geojson, marker, country

I am using Mapbox to build a multiple choropleth map.
Something along the lines of this example, https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/choropleth-joined-data-multiple-variables/

I am using countries instead of US states however.
I've got the map working and I can switch between layers
I have an extra requirement however to add a marker in each country that displays how many projects are active in that country.
I found out how I can add custom markers to the map with this example, https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/divicon/

The problem is I need to put a marker in the center of each country.
Does anybody know a way to put a marker in the middle of each country?

I tried to use the natural earth admin 0 label points data but that has multiple points per country. It looked like the 'scalerank=0' points were the middle of the countries but if I filter on these points, I still get multiple points for some countries (russia has 4 for instance, but Belgium has 4 as well).
If you plot all scalerank 0 points on a map you get the following result:
https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/persyval.jg5p7gm7/page.html?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicGVyc3l2YWwiLCJhIjoiX3lrSTNYYyJ9.6Ps4OlBCYmlkxQksKsGb7A#6/45.159/12.206

Does anybody know about a dataset that has one point per country or another way to put a marker in the center of each country with mapbox?

Answer (score 4):

It seems it's hard to find a list of country points for the placing of markers.
So I took the mentioned admin labal 0 points and tried to sanitize it to have only one appropiate marker per country.

The result can be downloaded here in GEOJSON format:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6IQhfb-UYeUYk1mcUZaMmV0S1U/edit?usp=sharing

If you want to have a visual representation of the points take a look at this map:
https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/persyval.jgk4767c/page.html?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicGVyc3l2YWwiLCJhIjoiX3lrSTNYYyJ9.6Ps4OlBCYmlkxQksKsGb7A#4/36.49/34.32

I needed this points for a proof of concept project so I haven't checked all markers meticulously, I also haven't taken account some of the more political sensitive country borders.
If you have a project in which this is of importance please check the file before using, but the points in this file can be easily edited to your own preferences.

Comment: I have the same problem and tried the same solution of using cultural point filtered by scalerank=0 and also noticed that there are many points per country. Thanks for creating a cleaned up version of this data.